Is there a built in way to pacman --ignore with a wildcard?
I'm currently manually parsing pacman's packages listed in the -Syyu output, manually filtering them for a keyword, and then adding them to the ignore list manually. eg. I grep for cuda then extract listed packages manually to: --ignore=cuda,cuda-tools,magma-cuda,etc
I could make my own script to do this but it feels like something pacman or bash has.
If not pacman, any chance yay or paru support this feature?
I'm not l33t enough to parse if this zsh code has wildcards, from pacman source (zsh completions), but it feels like I could just add some '*' to make it work. Also, the I read that the shell has wildcards built in but im not sure exactly how to use them in this case.
_pacman_completions_all_packages() {
    local -a seq sep cmd packages repositories packages_long
    _pacman_get_command

    if [[ ${words[CURRENT-1]} == '--ignore' ]]; then
        seq='_sequence'
        sep=(-S ',')
    else
        seq=
        sep=()
    fi

    if compset -P1 '*/*'; then
        packages=( $(_call_program packages $cmd[@] -Sql ${words[CURRENT]%/*}) )
        typeset -U packages
        ${seq} _wanted repo_packages expl "repository/package" compadd ${sep[@]} ${(@)packages}
    else
        packages=( $(_call_program packages $cmd[@] -Sql) )
        typeset -U packages
        ${seq} _wanted packages expl "packages" compadd ${sep[@]} - "${(@)packages}"

        repositories=($(pacman-conf --repo-list))
        typeset -U repositories
        _wanted repo_packages expl "repository/package" compadd -S "/" $repositories
    fi
}

